# Intallsing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in Acer Aspire 4736z

Tags: installation, acer

My laptop is Acer Aspire 4736z and installed windows 7 ultimate. Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside windows 7 in my laptop ?? I have same problem with this case: https://askubuntu.com/questions/121718/no-display-when-installing-ubuntu-on-an-acer-4736z

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install it via bootable CD and choosing the first Option to make it along side of windows 7 if you still want to use you win7 OS.
Please Note: that you need be very carefull in selecting or in-making the partition drive for ubuntu. And be sure backup all your data or use a Norton Ghost for assurance.